# Как вернуть текущий контекст класса, если вызывается метод родителя?

Tags: java, наследование, множественное-наследование

есть несколько классов:

```
// класс пользователя
public class User extends Select {
    public int user_id;
    public String user_name;
}

// класс select запроса
public class Select extends Where {
    public <T> T row() {
        (T) object.getClass().cast(object); // object - экземпляр User
    }
}

// класс составления условия запроса
public class Where {
    // and условие
    public ??? where() {
        return ???;
    }

    // or условие
    public ??? orWhere() {
        return ???;
    }

    // добавление внешнего условия в текущее условие
    public Where where(Where where) {
        this.concat(where); 

        return this;
    }
}
```

Нужно получить следующую возможность:

```
new User().where().row();
```

Или же

```
new User().where(new Where().orWhere()).row();
```

Можно ли такое провернуть? Если можно, то каким образом?

Comment: не совсем понятна идея... вы получили все методы по наследству и у экземпляра класса User можете вызвать любой из них, независимо от уровня наследника. Если метод переопределен, есть еще такая штука, как super для обращения к родительским методам.  какую именно хитрость вы хотите сделать?

Comment: Если я использую метод Where.where(), то дальше я уже не могу обращаться через цепь к методу Select.row(). А надо чтобы мог

Comment: А класс `Select` твой или уже дан "свыше"

Comment: что-то похожее можно сделать: https://www.sitepoint.com/self-types-with-javas-generics/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решается вот так:

```
// класс пользователя
public class User extends Select {
    public int user_id;
    public String user_name;
}

// класс select запроса
public class Select extends Where<Select> {
    public <T> T row() {
        (T) object.getClass().cast(object); // object - экземпляр User
    }
}

// класс составления условия запроса
public class Where<T extends Where<T>> {
    // and условие
    public T where() {
        return (T) this;
    }

    // or условие
    public T orWhere() {
        return (T) this;
    }

    // добавление внешнего условия в текущее условие
    public Where where(Where where) {
        this.concat(where); 

        return this;
    }
}
```