# Java. Пытыюсь из метода родительского класса вернуть существующий экземпляр расширяющего класса

Tags: java, generics

Доброго утра/дня/вечера/ночи,

Я столкнулся с необходимостью создания большого количества похожих классов. И методов похожих в каждом из них тоже много. И в главном методе также вынужден писать портянку из методов.

**Контекст:**  Есть много классов форм (`Form1`, `Form2`, ...`FormN`).  И все формы имеют метод подтверждения, который просто проверяет доступность кнопки подтверждения и нажиает её. На выходе мы имеем ту же форму, в которой мы нажимаем кнопку. Сразу скажу, `void` не катит... нужна именно форма.

Самым изящным решением (который я пока вижу, но рассмотрю любые предложения) будет: все необходимые методы вынести в общий родительский класс, но для выдерживания "цепочки" в главном методе я пытаюсь сделать эти методы параметризованными, чтобы они возвращали `(T) this;`.

И **тут я прошу помощи:** почему следующие два метода при дебаге показывают одно и тоже, но в первом случае возвращается экземпляр-предок, а не экземпляр-потомок:

```
public class Form {

    public <T extends Form> T confirm_1(){
        return  (T) this;
    }

    public <T extends Form> T confirm_2(T existingClassInstance){
        return  (T) this;
    }
}
```

Каждый раз передавать объект в качестве аргумента не эстетично, как и создавать метод `confirm()` в каждом классе `FormN` не правильно.

Поделитесь, пожалуйста, мыслями - как реализовать такое?

Заранее спасибо.
С уважением,
Алексей.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757871/

Comment: @zRrr,  
Спасибо огромное!